# Grid layout Web View - 2 rows 5 columns and in Mobile View 5 rows and 2 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to create 2 rows with 5 columns in web view and in mobile view grid layout should change it to 5 rows and 2 columns

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6">.col .</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

actually 'col" takes auto width inside the row but i need to restrict to 5 columns in 1 row and col-sm-6 has min-with:567 so that same layout overwrites in web view as well..

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="col-half col-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
```

Here is the css for the above

```
<style>
  .col-5{width: 20%;padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;box-sizing: border-box;}
  @media only screen 
  and (max-width : 480px) {
    .col-half{width: 50%;}
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I hope you will be using bootstrap in the project. If you feel any doubt, do write here